# What is the difference between the Kubo and Kubo-Greenwood formulas?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current

The general formula for linear response functions (and particularly for a conductivity) is referred to as the Kubo formula or the Kubo-Greendoow formula. **What is the difference between them?**

In the [original paper by R. Kubo](https://journals.jps.jp/doi/10.1143/JPSJ.12.570), the following formula (2.23b) for the response function is derived:
$$
\phi_{BA}(\omega)=-\frac{i}\hbar\int\langle[\hat{A},\hat{B}(t)]\rangle e^{i(\omega+i\delta)t}dt
$$
(I have changed the original notation $e^{i\omega t}$ for time oscillations to $e^{-i\omega t}$ and taken the pure ground state for simplicity).

In the [paper by D.A. Greenwood](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0370-1328/71/4/306), the following formula (31) can be found:
$$
\sigma=-2\pi e^2\hbar\int\sum_{mn}|v_{mn}|^2\delta(E-E_n)\delta(E-E_m)\frac{\partial f}{\partial E}dE.
$$
It refers to the static limit and seems to be rather different (at least, by the initial problem statement) from the Kubo formula.

Answer (score 2):

The Kubo formula for conductivity is obtained in (5.20) of the [original Kubo paper](https://journals.jps.jp/doi/10.1143/JPSJ.12.570):
$$
\sigma_{\mu\nu}(\omega)= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i\omega t} \,dt  
\int_{0}^{\beta}  d\lambda \,\langle j_\nu (-i\hbar\lambda)\,j_\mu(t)\rangle .
$$
The Kubo–Greenwood formula is a non-interacting approximation of the the Kubo formula. The derivation is explained in some detail [here](http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/%7Eallen/Pubs/elec-trans-rev.pdf), where the Kubo equation above appears in (17). In the non-interacting case the current operator can be written as (23)
$$
\hat{j}_x=\sum_{nm}\langle n|j_x|m\rangle c_n^\dagger c_m e^{i(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m)t/\hbar}
$$
which substituted in the Kubo equation above yields (25)
$$ \sigma_{\mu\nu}(\omega)=\frac{i\hbar}V \sum_{mn}
\frac{f_n- f_m} {\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n}
\frac{\langle n|j_\nu|m \rangle \langle m|j_\mu|n \rangle}
{\hbar(\omega + i\eta) - (\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n) },
$$
directly related for $\omega=0$  to the Kubo-Greenwood equation above.

PS I have no access to the Greenwood paper.